# Translating Docker syntax

Tags: docker

I am trying to get this image to run using WSL on Windows 10 and I am wondering if someone could clear up what some of this syntax means.

```
# you need to specify the input directory
export input_dir=/home/input_dir   
# make that directory
sudo mkdir $input_dir
# put dicom images to the $input_dir directly without subfolders
# set output directory
export output_dir=$input_dir/output
#run the docker if your input_dir contains dicom files
sudo docker run -it --rm -v $input_dir:/INPUTS/ -v $output_dir:/OUTPUTS masidocker/public:liver_attenuation_v3_0_3 /extra/run_deep_wholebody_dicom.sh
```

I understand that first we are creating a folder path and storing it in an environment variable. Then the directory is created, and again we create another folder path and store it in an environment variable. I know that `--rm` is used to remove the container once process is finished. I am not sure about the `-it` or the `-v` parameters. Is this section `$input_dir:/INPUTS/` giving the alias of INPUTS to the $input_dir directory? I am not sure what that part is doing. The end part is just referencing a image to run and then a shell script that lives inside the image?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
sudo docker run 
-it # This will attach an interactive terminal to the container so that you can execute the command in the container
--rm # Remove the container when container exit
-v $input_dir:/INPUTS/ # Bind mount your host directory to the container directory
-v $output_dir:/OUTPUTS # Bind mount your host directory to the container directory
masidocker/public:liver_attenuation_v3_0_3 # The image use to run the container
/extra/run_deep_wholebody_dicom.sh # The command to execute inside the container
```